# Flutter GestureDetector doesn't call the function in an if else expression

Tags: flutter, dart

`onPanUpdate` is supposed to be called when `isEnabled` is true. But when `isEnabled` is true, `onPanUpdate` is not invoked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  var offset = Offset.zero;
  bool isEnabled = false;

  void onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    offset += details.delta;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: offset,
          child: Listener(
            onPointerDown: (event) {
              setState(() {
                isEnabled = true;
              });
            },
            onPointerUp: (event) {
              setState(() {
                isEnabled = false;
              });
            },
            child: GestureDetector(
              onPanUpdate: isEnabled ? (d) => onPanUpdate(d) : null,
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 300,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try renaming onPanUpdate(d) and change from null to  (d) {}

Comment: It works if I change null to `(d) {}`, it works. But why doesn't work if I set it to null? @DungNgo

Comment: i try your code again, and it works fine for me. Can you check if you did the onPanUpdate action correct?

Comment: `onPanUpdate` is working correctly. As you said if I change null to `(d) {}` then it works. But setting as null doesn't work.

Comment: Glad it works for you. As for why setting it to null doesn't work, i honestly don't remember. It's just that i once ran into a bug where i set null to my onTap() and when i changed it to () {}, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

@DungNgo is correct in saying that setting onPanUpdate to null causes this problem.

As for the reasons, Let me try to explain:

On the first build, When **onPanUpdate was null** because `isEnabled` is false, `GestureDetector` did not create the `PanGestureRecognizer`.

```
class GestureDetector extends StatelessWidget {
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (onPanDown != null ||
        onPanStart != null ||
        onPanUpdate != null ||
        onPanEnd != null ||
        onPanCancel != null) {
      gestures[PanGestureRecognizer] = GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<PanGestureRecognizer>(
        () => PanGestureRecognizer(debugOwner: this),
        (PanGestureRecognizer instance) {
          instance
            ..onDown = onPanDown
            ..onStart = onPanStart
            ..onUpdate = onPanUpdate
            ..onEnd = onPanEnd
            ..onCancel = onPanCancel
            ..dragStartBehavior = dragStartBehavior;
        },
      );
    }
  }
  return RawGestureDetector(
    gestures: gestures,
    behavior: behavior,
    excludeFromSemantics: excludeFromSemantics,
    child: child,
  );
}
```

When the finger is pressed, the `Listener` performs an `onPointerDown` callback, sets `isEnabled` to true, and updates the UI.

At this point, `GestureDetector` performs a second build, this time **onPanUpdate is not null**, and the `PanGestureRecognizer` is created.

However, if you have any idea of the gesture event with Flutter, you will know that the gesture needs to be added to the gesture arena to be recognized, and the gesture needs to be recognized to trigger the corresponding callback.

This addition is added in the **next onPointerDown** after the gesture recognizer is created.

```
class RawGestureDetectorState extends State<RawGestureDetector> {
  void _handlePointerDown(PointerDownEvent event) {
    assert(_recognizers != null);
    for (final GestureRecognizer recognizer in _recognizers!.values)
      recognizer.addPointer(event);
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget result = Listener(
      onPointerDown: _handlePointerDown,
      behavior: widget.behavior ?? _defaultBehavior,
      child: widget.child,
    );
    if (!widget.excludeFromSemantics)
      result = _GestureSemantics(
        child: result,
        assignSemantics: _updateSemanticsForRenderObject,
      );
    return result;
  }
}
```

But depending on your code, **onPointerUp will set isEnabled to false**.

As a result, gestures are never added to the arena/

So it never invoke `onPanUpdate` .

hope helpful ^_^